# Reflection returns backing fields of read-only properties?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, .net-4.6, .net-4.6.2

It looks like Reflection returns the backing fields for properties if called like so:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

Is there a way to return all fields which have been declared by the user in the class without any backing fields / compiler-generated fields / etc.?

**EDIT:** Is it safe to rely on the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute?

Comment: Safety is not binary. The question "is it safe" should be "is it safe enough", which in turn prompts the counterquestion "safe enough for what?" Consider that it's possible to create types dynamically at runtime, which contain fields indistinguishable from those in compile-time defined types. Consider also that there are common libraries that create such types at runtime, and that there is no info in your question about whether you're using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All such fields are marked with CompilerGeneratedAttribute, so you can filter like this:

```
var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null).ToArray();
```